# How to use other parameters with an event included

Tags: javascript, function, events

I have this function:

```
function searchItem(e, pageNumber){
  e.preventDefault();
  searchString = searchBox.value;
  article = document.getElementById("homeSection");
  var xmlhttp = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
  var string = '';
  if(xmlhttp){
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
          var price = parseFloat(response[i].Price);
          string += '<section class="searchResult">';
          string += '<p class="photo"><img src="' + response[i].Photo + '"></p>';
          string += '<section>';
          string += '<h1 class="name">' + response[i].Name + '</h1>';
          string += '<p class="price">£' + price.toFixed(2) + '</p>';
          string += '<p class="description">' + response[i].Description + '</p>';
          string += '<p class="productID">ID: ' + response[i].ID + '</p>';
          string += '<p class="quantity">Quantity: ' + response[i].Quantity + '</p>';
          string += '</section>';
          string += '</section>';
          if(pageNumber != 1){
            string += '<section><button id=previousPage>Previous</button><button id=nextPage>Next</button></section>';
          }
        }
        article.innerHTML = '<h1>Search</h1><section><h1 class="bottomBorder">You searched for: "' + searchString + '"</h1></section>';
        article.innerHTML += string;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "search.php?search=" + searchString, false);
    xmlhttp.send("&rpp=" + rowsPerPage + "&last=" + lastPage + "&page=" + pageNumber);
  }
}
```

What I am curious about is how to call the function because it expects an event.
It worked fine when I was using it in a javascript event handler:

```
searchButton.addEventListener("click", searchItem);
```

but when i tried calling the function with parameters like this it didn't work, it tells me that e is not defined:

```
searchButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  searchItem(1);
});
```

Which I do understand because I haven't passed through a parameter for `e` but I want to know is why it works as an event without a pseudo function and how I should call it with a pseudo function.

Comment: 1 is not an event...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function requires the `event` as the first argument. This is set when using the function itself as the click handler, but when you create your own click handler, you need to capture the `event` and explicitly pass it:

```
searchButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  //                 capture the event object--^
  searchItem(e, 1);
  //         ^ pass it to the function
});
```